# Text with either custom OR system font size (and how to get that number) - SwiftUI

Tags: text, swiftui, font-size

Can I do something like below?

```
Text(text)
    .font(.system(size: (textSize != nil) ? textSize! : Font.body))
```

How do I get to the number behind `Font.body`? Or how to switch between custom and system size?

There is no `Font.body.size` property.

Comment: There is no fix size that you are looking! Font.body acts differently depending on device or starting text or zoomed and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you wanted something like

```
Text(text)
    .font(textSize != nil ? .system(size: textSize!) : Font.body)
```

Comment: Ahhh, instead of switching only on the size, I can switch on the whole font instead. This totally does it, thanks.

Comment: @Big_Chair: So then your question is not right and clear! You asked "How do I get to the number behind Font.body?"